# Why use Octopus plugin in Atlassian Bamboo?

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo, continuous-deployment, octopus-deploy

We are currently trying to explore the advantages of having an Octopus + Bamboo in our current build and release process.

I am still not 100% convinced that an Octopus + Bamboo setup will significantly increase efficiency and quality of our deployments as I still find it redundant.

However, I do want to know some examples in your build and release setup that you are able to do exclusively with Octopus + Bamboo.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you rephrase your question, or describe your current build and release process? What sort of problems do you have, what are your long terms goals, etc?

Comment: Our build and release process is basically this at the moment:
- We build the code in Bamboo
- We package the code in Bamboo inside an RPM
- Deploy the release to test
- If successful on test, promote same package to live

What I want to achieve now is to have a CI for our Database changes but I don't know where to begin...